# How to subscribe to empty Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I've got a function which returns Observable if one condition is met:

```
private function() {
    for (let element of this.array) {
        if (element.id == this.element2.id) {
            return Observable.fromPromise(this.databaseProvider.selectFor(element.id));
        }
    }
    // return Observable.of();
}
```

and subscribing to it:

```
this.function().subscribe(id => {
    if (id) {
        // do something with value
    } else {
        // do something without value
    }
}
```

I tried returning `Observable.of()` outside the for loop but condition inside `.subscribe()` doesn't work as I wanted.

Comment: are you checking with strict equals `===` ? please share some more code of the angular service and component

Comment: return Observable.of(null)? or return Observable.of(0)?

Comment: @Eliseo thanks, that works. I thought that `Observable.of()` returns null by default.